# filterhashtable filter by event code

Tags: powershell, hashtable, event-log

Is it possible to filter event logs by its codes range, or inequality using filterhashtable?
Something like:

```
$filter = @{
    LogName = 'application'
    Level = 2,3
    ID = isBetween 2000 and 4000 and -ne 3333 => ?
}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @filter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx) ID must be a list of integers only.

> -- ID=`<Int32[]`>

Answer (score 3):

As Andy has said, ID needs to be a list of numbers, but you can build the ID number list yourself (I had previously posted an incomplete answer but have fixed my own code).

The following should do the trick:

```
[int32[]]$ID = @(2000..3332 + 3334..4000)
$filter = @{Logname='Application';
            Level=2,3;
            ID=$ID}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter
```

Comment: Weird...  i tried this and it worked, but the biggest range i could get to work was about 20 ID's.

Comment: Strange - what's your windows version and powershell version?

Comment: I'm using powershell version 4.0.1.1 running on windows server 2012R2.   The target remote machines are all windows 7.  When it fails, it apparently is the remote machine responding with something like nothing found that meets the criteria.  I Bingled and found others saying they had problems above 22 ID's.  I would just be cautious if you don't get back any responses.  Perhaps it's only remote machines that are problem.  BTW, I was gleeful when i saw your solution; i thought for sure it would solve my problem.  The upvote you got today was me.

Comment: Ah - I've only used it local, not remote. Will do some testing